# Attach to Event of Sibling Control in Custom WPF Control Initialization

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a WPF custom slider control that acts as a scrollbar for a Listview. I'm doing this by putting the name of the listview in the Tag attribute of my custom slider and then using the slider's OnValueChange event to scroll the listview. This works great, however, when I scroll in the listview with my mousewheel the slider doesn't move. What I need is a way to attach a method to the listview's MouseWheel event when my custom slider initializes. Here is what I've tried:

Custom slider class:

```
public class LabeledScrollbar : Slider
{
    public override void EndInit()
    {
        var listbox = (ListBox)this.FindName(this.Tag.ToString());
        if (listbox != null)
        {
            listbox.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(this.OnMouseWheel);
        }
        base.EndInit();
    }

    protected void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Value += 5;
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        var listBox = (ListBox)this.FindName(this.Tag.ToString());
        var collection = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox.ItemsSource);

        if (newValue == this.Maximum)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(listBox) > 0)
            {
                var chrome = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBox, 0);
                var scrollView = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(chrome, 0);
                scrollView.ScrollToTop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var index = (collection.Count - 1) - (int)Math.Floor(newValue);
            var selectedItem = collection.GetItemAt(index);
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(selectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewCategories"> 
    ... 
</ListView>
<local:LabeledScrollbar x:Name="categoryScrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Tag="listViewCategories"></local:LabeledScrollbar>
```

While it seems like OnMouseWheel should fire when the I scroll in the listview, it's not happening and I haven't been able to find anything else to try. Is there a way to do what I want in WPF? I know I could put a method in the code behind of my view to make the MouseScroll event of the listview move the slider, but I was hoping to encapsulate as much of the logic for the slider in the slider class as possible.

Comment: What binding does your xaml contain to hook up slider scroll with listbox. The logic you want to achieve is definitely achievable by binding properly

Comment: @Versatile I added the XAML. As you can see, I'm not doing anything there except putting the name of the listview in the tag. Then I use the tag to look up the listview in my custom slider class. Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to bind a control's property to another control's property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the trick was to use PreviewMouseWheel instead of MouseWheel. For future reference here is my current class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class creates a custom control that can be used as a scrollbar for a listbox that displays the current
/// group visible in the listbox on a small label next to the slider thumb.
/// 
/// To use it, set the Tag value to the name of the listbox the scollbar will be controlling.
/// </summary>
public class LabeledScrollbar : Slider
{
    //Tracks control initialization to ensure it only gets loaded once
    private bool initialized = false;

    //The listview this slider will control
    private ListView listView;

    public LabeledScrollbar(): base()
    {
        this.Loaded += LabeledScrollbar_Loaded;
    }

    void LabeledScrollbar_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //The tag must be set to the name of a listbox
        listView = (ListView)this.FindName(this.Tag.ToString());

        if (listView != null && !this.initialized)
        {
            //Make sure that the mouse wheel event in the linked listbox is handled
            listView.PreviewMouseWheel += (s, ev) =>
            {
                if (ev.Delta > 0)
                    this.Value += 3;
                else
                    this.Value -= 3;
            };

            //Move scrollbar and list to the top if the collection changes
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)listView.Items).CollectionChanged += (s, ev) =>
            {
                this.Maximum = ((ItemCollection)listView.Items).Count - 1;
                this.Value = this.Maximum;
            };

            //Get the max value of the slider by checking the tag value and looking up the associated listbox
            this.Maximum = ((ItemCollection)listView.Items).Count - 1;
            this.Value = this.Maximum;
            this.initialized = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        //Refresh the tickbar so that it will render for a new value
        InvalidateTickbar();

        //Scroll the list box to the correct location
        ScrollToIndex(newValue);
    }

    private void ScrollToIndex(double newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == this.Maximum)
        {
            //ScrollIntoView method does not scroll to the top so 
            //we need to access the scrollview to move the slider to the top
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(listView) > 0)
            {
                var chrome = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listView, 0);
                var scrollView = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(chrome, 0);
                scrollView.ScrollToTop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var collection = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
            var index = (collection.Count - 1) - (int)Math.Floor(newValue);
            var selectedItem = collection.GetItemAt(index);
            listView.ScrollIntoView(selectedItem);
        }
    }

    private void InvalidateTickbar()
    {
        //update the tickbar for the new position
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this) > 0)
        {
            var firstChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0);
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(firstChild) > 0)
            {
                var secondChild = (CustomTickBar)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(firstChild, 0);
                secondChild.InvalidateVisual();
            }
        }
    }
}
```